# Multiplying functions depending on a previous input

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to do a little script that writes an html file, this file must have a table which contains two rows that have some information about different products, I managed to get this done, but now I need that this table repeats as many times depending on a previous input data, so for this I thought I could multiply the function which contains the html code but it doesn't work, actually I'm not quite sure what I'm doing here so a little bit of help wouldn't be bad...

This is what I want:

Input ---> How many tables: 3

So the html output file should look something like this

```
<-- TABLE 1 -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" height="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="width6p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_1" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/image/CODEPRODUCT_1" width="230" alt="DESCRIPTION_1" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
    <td width="30" class="width3p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_2" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/image/CODEPRODUCT_2" width="230" alt="DESCRIPTION_2" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">DESCRIPTION_1</span ><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14"> DESCRIPTION_1</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: CODEPRODUCT_-1</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">PRICE_1</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">DESCRIPTION_2</span><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14"> DESCRIPTION_2</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: CODEPRODUCT_-2</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">PRICE_2</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_1" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_2" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<-- TABLE 2 -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" height="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="width6p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_1" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/image/CODEPRODUCT_1" width="230" alt="DESCRIPTION_1" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
    <td width="30" class="width3p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_2" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/image/CODEPRODUCT_2" width="230" alt="DESCRIPTION_2" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">DESCRIPTION_1</span ><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14"> DESCRIPTION_1</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: CODEPRODUCT_-1</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">PRICE_1</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">DESCRIPTION_2</span><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14"> DESCRIPTION_2</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: CODEPRODUCT_-2</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">PRICE_2</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_1" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_2" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<-- TABLE 3 -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" height="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="width6p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_1" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/image/CODEPRODUCT_1" width="230" alt="DESCRIPTION_1" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
    <td width="30" class="width3p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_2" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/image/CODEPRODUCT_2" width="230" alt="DESCRIPTION_2" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">DESCRIPTION_1</span ><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14"> DESCRIPTION_1</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: CODEPRODUCT_-1</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">PRICE_1</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">DESCRIPTION_2</span><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14"> DESCRIPTION_2</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: CODEPRODUCT_-2</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">PRICE_2</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_1" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/site/product/CODEPRODUCT_2" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my Python code

```
import locale
import requests
import urlparse
import json

def html(sku_01,desc_01,sku_precio_1,sku_02,desc_02,sku_precio_2,bloque_prod):

  f = open('mkt-output.html','w')
  f.write(bloque_prod)
  f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  sku_01 = raw_input('Ingrese SKU: ')
  desc_01 = raw_input('Descripcion de SKU: ')
  sku_precio_1 = raw_input('Precio de SKU: ')
  sku_02 = raw_input('Ingrese SKU: ')
  desc_02 = raw_input('Descripcion de SKU: ')
  sku_precio_2 = raw_input('Precio de SKU: ')
  bloque_prod = """<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" height="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="width6p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/images/{}" width="230" alt="{}" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
    <td width="30" class="width3p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/images/{}" width="230" alt="{}" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">{}</span ><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14">{} {}</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: {}-{}</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">{}</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">{}</span><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14">{} {}</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: {}-{}</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">{}</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/templates/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/templates/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>""".format(sku_01,
  sku_01,
  desc_01,
  sku_02,
  sku_02,
  desc_02,
  ' '.join(desc_01.split()[0:3]),
  ' '.join(desc_01.split()[3:-1]),
  desc_01.split()[-1],
  sku_01[0:-1],
  sku_01[-1],
  sku_precio_1,
  ' '.join(desc_02.split()[0:3]),
  ' '.join(desc_02.split()[3:-1]),
  desc_02.split()[-1],
  sku_02[0:-1],
  sku_02[-1],
  sku_precio_2,
  sku_01,
  sku_02)

html(sku_01, desc_01, sku_precio_1, sku_02, desc_02, sku_precio_2, bloque_prod)
```

Comment: Multiply the string returned by `format()` with the requested number of repetitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need duplicate data written to the HTML file, you could simply have the `html()` function write variable `bloque_prod` multiple times by multiplying it:

```
def html(sku_01,desc_01,sku_precio_1,sku_02,desc_02,sku_precio_2,bloque_prod,tables):

  f = open('mkt-output.html','w')
  f.write(bloque_prod * tables)
  f.close()
```

Note the addition of the variable `tables` for the number of table duplicates.

Then, define variable `tables` in `__main()__`:

```
tables = input('Tables: ')
```

…and add `tables` into the last line where you call `html()`

```
html(sku_01, desc_01, sku_precio_1, sku_02, desc_02, sku_precio_2, bloque_prod,tables)
```

Are you looking to write different tables?

Also, if it's necessary to annotate which table is currently being printed, you could add an if statement in:

```
def html(sku_01,desc_01,sku_precio_1,sku_02,desc_02,sku_precio_2,bloque_prod,tables):
  f = open('mkt-output.html','w')
  rawHTML = ""
  for table in range(0, tables):
        rawHTML += ("\n<-- TABLE " + str(table) + " -->\n" + bloque_prod)
  f.write(rawHTML)
  f.close()
```

(if you wanted the numbering to start at 1, you'd just change `str(table)` to `str(table + 1)`)

--EDIT-- It seems that you are looking to create tables with different values. I would rewrite the program as such to do this:

```
import locale
import requests
import urlparse
import json

def createTable(sku_01,desc_01,sku_precio_1,sku_02,desc_02,sku_precio_2):
  bloque_prod = """<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" height="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50" class="width6p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/images/{}" width="230" alt="{}" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
    <td width="30" class="width3p"></td>
    <td width="260" class="width44p"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://site/images/{}" width="230" alt="{}" style="display:block" border="0" class="width90p"/></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">{}</span ><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14">{} {}</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: {}-{}</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">{}</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="font14" valign="top" style=" font-size: 16px; inline-height:0px; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:lighter; color:#666666; line-height:130%; padding:10px 0px;">
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA" class="font14">{}</span><br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#008EAA; font-size:14px;" class="font14">{} {}</span><br/>
      <span style="font-size:12px;" class="font12">SKU: {}-{}</span><br />
      <span style="font-size:18px;" class="font14">$ </span>
      <span style="font-size:24px; line-height:30px;" class="font20">{}</span>
      <span style="font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase;" class="font10"> C/U</span> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/templates/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td style="inline-height:0px;padding-top:4px;"><a href="http://www.site/product/{}" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.site/templates/images/loquiero_med.png" width="142" title="Ver producto" style="display:block" border="0" class="width115"/></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>""".format(sku_01,
  sku_01,
  desc_01,
  sku_02,
  sku_02,
  desc_02,
  ' '.join(desc_01.split()[0:3]),
  ' '.join(desc_01.split()[3:-1]),
  desc_01.split()[-1],
  sku_01[0:-1],
  sku_01[-1],
  sku_precio_1,
  ' '.join(desc_02.split()[0:3]),
  ' '.join(desc_02.split()[3:-1]),
  desc_02.split()[-1],
  sku_02[0:-1],
  sku_02[-1],
  sku_precio_2,
  sku_01,
  sku_02)
  return bloque_prod

if __name__ == "__main__":
  f = open('mkt-output.html','w+') # Open file in w+ mode so we can append to the end
  for table in range(0,input("Tables: ")):
        print ("--Table "+str(table)+"--")
        sku_01 = raw_input('Ingrese SKU: ')
        desc_01 = raw_input('Descripcion de SKU: ')
        sku_precio_1 = raw_input('Precio de SKU: ')
        sku_02 = raw_input('Ingrese SKU: ')
        desc_02 = raw_input('Descripcion de SKU: ')
        sku_precio_2 = raw_input('Precio de SKU: ')
        f.write(createTable(sku_01,desc_01,sku_precio_1,sku_02,desc_02,sku_precio_2))
  f.close()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm going to try this but I think this is going to print the table with the same information many time as I specify, to be more specific I want that the table repeats as many times I specify in the input but with diferent information, so I can add diferents products in the same template of the table.

Comment: If it's what you're looking for, you can mark it as correct.